# How to split a dataframe by unique groups and save to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a pandas dataframe I would like to iterate over. A simplified example of my dataframe:

```
chr    start    end    Gene    Value   MoreData
chr1    123    123    HAPPY    41.1    3.4
chr1    125    129    HAPPY    45.9    4.5
chr1    140    145    HAPPY    39.3   4.1
chr1    342    355    SAD    34.2    9.0
chr1    360    361    SAD    44.3    8.1
chr1    390    399    SAD    29.0   7.2
chr1    400    411    SAD    35.6   6.5
chr1    462    470    LEG    20.0    2.7
```

I would like to iterate over each unique gene and create a new file named:

```
for Gene in df: ## this is where I need the most help

    OutFileName = Gene+".pdf"
```

For the above example I should get three iterations with 3 outfiles and 3 dataframes:

```
# HAPPY.pdf
chr1    123    123    HAPPY    41.1    3.4 
chr1    125    129    HAPPY    45.9    4.5 
chr1    140    145    HAPPY    39.3   4.1

# SAD.pdf
chr1    342    355    SAD    34.2    9.0 
chr1    360    361    SAD  44.3    8.1 
chr1    390    399    SAD    29.0   7.2 
chr1    400    411    SAD    35.6   6.5

# Leg.pdf
chr1    462    470    LEG    20.0    2.7
```

The resulting data frame contents split up by chunks will be sent to another function that will perform the analysis and return the contents to be written to file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can obtain the unique values calling `unique`, iterate over this, build the filename and write this out to csv:

```
genes = df['Gene'].unique()
for gene in genes:
    outfilename = gene + '.pdf'
    print(outfilename)
    df[df['Gene'] == gene].to_csv(outfilename)
HAPPY.pdf
SAD.pdf
LEG.pdf
```

A more pandas-thonic method is to groupby on `'Gene'` and then iterate over the groups:

```
gp = df.groupby('Gene')
# groups() returns a dict with 'Gene':indices as k:v pair
for g in gp.groups.items():
    print(df.loc[g[1]])   
    
    chr  start  end   Gene  Value  MoreData
0  chr1    123  123  HAPPY   41.1       3.4
1  chr1    125  129  HAPPY   45.9       4.5
2  chr1    140  145  HAPPY   39.3       4.1
    chr  start  end Gene  Value  MoreData
3  chr1    342  355  SAD   34.2       9.0
4  chr1    360  361  SAD   44.3       8.1
5  chr1    390  399  SAD   29.0       7.2
6  chr1    400  411  SAD   35.6       6.5
    chr  start  end Gene  Value  MoreData
7  chr1    462  470  LEG     20       2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

- It's cleaner to groupby the column, and then save the associated group to the csv file.

  - **This solution only requires 2 lines of code.**
  - Aggregation of other functions can be performed when doing the `.groupby()`, or within the loop.
- When used without an aggregation, [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returns the dataframe components associated with each unique value from the groupby column.

  - `.groups.items():` is not used in the following code, which makes it easy to use `group` as the filename.
  - The following code will create a file for the data associated to each unique value in the column used to groupby.
- Use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to create a unique filename for each `group`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
data = {'chr': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'], 'start': [123, 125, 140, 342, 360, 390, 400, 462], 'end': [123, 129, 145, 355, 361, 399, 411, 470], 'Gene': ['HAPPY', 'HAPPY', 'HAPPY', 'SAD', 'SAD', 'SAD', 'SAD', 'LEG'], 'Value': [41.1, 45.9, 39.3, 34.2, 44.3, 29.0, 35.6, 20.0], 'MoreData': [3.4, 4.5, 4.1, 9.0, 8.1, 7.2, 6.5, 2.7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby the desired column and iterate through the groupby object
for group, dataframe in df.groupby('Gene'):
    
    # save the dataframe for each group to a csv
    dataframe.to_csv(f'{group}.csv', index=False)
```

### Results

- `HAPPY.csv`

```
chr,start,end,Gene,Value,MoreData
chr1,123,123,HAPPY,41.1,3.4
chr1,125,129,HAPPY,45.9,4.5
chr1,140,145,HAPPY,39.3,4.1
```

- `SAD.csv`

```
chr,start,end,Gene,Value,MoreData
chr1,342,355,SAD,34.2,9.0
chr1,360,361,SAD,44.3,8.1
chr1,390,399,SAD,29.0,7.2
chr1,400,411,SAD,35.6,6.5
```

- `LEG.csv`

```
chr,start,end,Gene,Value,MoreData
chr1,462,470,LEG,20.0,2.7
```