# split large csv based on one column condition and write to smaller csv

Tags: python, pandas

How can I split a large csv with many columns, based on changing one column e.g ID? here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
csvdata = StringIO("""ID,f1
1,3.2
1,4.3
1,10
7,9.1
7,2.3
7,4.4
""") 

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
df
```

My aim is to save each block in separate csv which its name is generated in a loop based on ID:

```
df_ID_1.csv

    ID f1
    1  3.2
    1  4.3
    1  10.0

df_ID_7.csv

    ID f1
    7  9.1
    7  2.3
    7  4.4
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103676/pandas-split-dataframe-on-id-and-write-to-csv-with-generated-filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just cycle through the IDs, create a sliced dataframe for each one, and create your .csv file

```
for id in df['ID'].unique():
    temp_df = df.loc[df['ID'] == id]
    file_name = "df_ID_{}".format(id)
    # make the path to where you want it saved
    file_path = "C:/Users/you/Desktop/" + file_name
    # write the single ID dataframe to a csv
    temp_df.to_csv(file_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `groupby` method for this and acces each seperate group and write it to a csv using `pandas.to_csv`.

```
for _, r in df.groupby('ID'):
    r.to_csv(f'df_ID_{r.ID.iloc[0]}')
```

Or if your Python version is < 3.5 use `.format` for string formatting instead of `f-string`:

```
for _, r in df.groupby('ID'):
    r.to_csv('df_ID_{}.csv'.format(r.ID.iloc[0]))
```

Which splits our dataframe in seperate csv's:
[image: csv's]

**Explanation** of the loop we use:

```
for _, r in df.groupby('ID'):
    print(r, '\n')
    print(f'This is our ID {r.ID.iloc[0]}', '\n')

   ID    f1
0   1   3.2
1   1   4.3
2   1  10.0 

This is our ID 1 

   ID   f1
3   7  9.1
4   7  2.3
5   7  4.4 

This is our ID 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Pandas: read the file using the `csv module`, sort by the specified *column*, groupby the specified *column* using the `itertools` module, iterate over the groups and write new files.

```
import itertools, csv

key = operator.itemgetter('ID')
# assumes csvdata is a filelike object (io.StringIO in OP's example)
reader = csv.DictReader(csvdata)
fields = reader.fieldnames
data = sorted(reader, key = key)
for key,group in itertools.groupby(data, key):
    with open(f'ID_{key}.csv', 'w')as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(group)
```