# Split per attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a big CSV. Then split big CSV into smaller CSV files, based on unique values in the column `team`.
At first I created new dataframes for each `team`. The new txt files generated, one for each unique value in `team` column.

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('combined.csv')
df = df[df.team == 'RED']
df.to_csv('RED.csv')
```

However I want to start from a single dataframe, read all unique 'teams', and create a .txt file for each team, with headers.
Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: split dataframe on values of ID column and write to csv, generate filenames from values in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103676/pandas-split-dataframe-on-values-of-id-column-and-write-to-csv-generate-filena)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), when used without an aggregation, returns the dataframe components associated with each group in the groupby column.
- The following code will create a file for the data associated to each unique value in the column used to groupby.
- Use [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to create a unique filename for each group.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('combined.csv')

# groupby the desired column and iterate through the groupby object
for group, dataframe in df.groupby('team'):
    
    # save the dataframe for each group to a csv
    dataframe.to_csv(f'{group}.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks works fine. I  am new to Python. Is this print formatting : f'{group}.txt'

Comment: @Anonymus It's an f-string. So you can cleanly place a variable in a string.

Comment: This is a cleaner more legible solution to the 2014 asking [Pandas: split dataframe on values of ID column and write to csv, generate filenames from values in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103676/pandas-split-dataframe-on-id-and-write-to-csv-with-generated-filenames). I wish we could close that one into this, but we can't...

Comment: @smci Yes I was just looking at that after you posted it, and thinking the same thing.

Comment: @smci I looked for a duplicate before posting, but I didn't find it

Comment: No worries. I just searched on column, unique values, group, to_csv...

Comment: @smci I added an updated answer there too. I will get more views than this question

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: I feel like I morally deserve 'affiliate referral bonus'... :-)